# Get area size - Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

How could I get the X or the Y value from the images below?
My goal is to monitoring the level variance, any other suggestions are welcome!

I've tried the suggestion from @HansHirse on [How to get the area of the contours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467031/how-to-get-the-area-of-the-contours) but it didn't work properly for the red image (as the red one has low bright).

Note: the color will vary.

Blue image:
[image]

Red image:
[image]

Original images
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide your input image without x and y notation

Comment: I am confused. Are you showing each (R,G,B) channel of one input. Or do you have different colored input images. If the latter, how are the colors chosen?  Do you always have one of each color? Do you have other colors? Do you know ahead what color the image will be?

Comment: @fmw42 we have different colored input images - unfortunately we can't control the colors, can be any (orange, pink, blue, purple, etc)

Comment: Do we know the left end is always a brighter, more saturated version of a similar hue at the right end?

Comment: Hey @MarkSetchell the most cases are a brighter similar color at the left end - sometimes it can be white as well

Comment: Is there a finite list of colors? Or is totally arbitrary? Is it ever white/gray/black in color or always a non-gray color?

Comment: @fmw42 there is no finite list of colors - can be any color and always a non-gray color.

Long story short: these images are photos from a glass screen. Inside this glass screen is passing a fluid. This fluid can be any color and that is the reason we don't have control about the colors.

Thanks in advance.