# How to get the area of a contour on a 3D surface from a single photo?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm beginning to work on a project with OpenCV (in python), and I'm trying to figure out the best way to tackle the problem I'm facing. I'm trying to get the area of an item in an image...but the surface area I'm looking for is on a 3D object.

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467031/how-to-get-the-area-of-the-contours) while searching for calculating the area of a contour, but as you can see, this is only for a 2D object. For example, how could I find the area of the red question marks on the sphere in [this](https://previews.123rf.com/images/megaloman1ac/megaloman1ac1507/megaloman1ac150700583/42584569-3d-ball-with-question-marks-and-exclamation-mark.jpg) image? Or the size of the rash on [this](https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/slideshows/birthmarks_slideshow/650x350_birthmarks_slideshow.jpg) baby's face (which is most certainly not 2-dimensional)? Is there a way to find the depth of the surface in the image, then use the high color gradient difference to find contours and calculate the difference based on the depths?

I found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08527) deep learning paper (and associated PyTorch library), but was wondering if there was another way that I was missing...

Thanks to all for any ideas / replies.

Comment: This isnt possible without additional information or assimptions. For example how should be algorithm know whether it is a very big baby face far away from the camera or s very small baby face close to the camera? Same for the sphere. If you know the size and shape of the whole object and want to measure an image-based part of that object this is possible but not simple (for complex shapes).

Comment: Assumptions: it will be the same object (for example, a face) directly facing the camera from 12 inches distance. Additionally, in each image there will be an inch-by-inch block that will be used to standardize measurements (e.g. a checkerboard pattern). Would it be possible then?

Comment: depends on the accuracy. If you are able to create the 3D geometry of that face you can use solvePnp with facial landmarks and afterwards project every pixel to 3D position and measure 3D regions directly.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between a face and a book with an image of a face on it? Deep learning algorithms learn to do single shot depth estimation by developing strong priors which lead to strong biases. if you don't care about your accuracy you can just measure the relation of the face length or width to the surface area according to some phantom and just use that instead of using complicated algorithms.